# Temporary Neo4j database to test services

Tags: java, junit, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm building a Spring Application using a Neo4j database.
I have some services, that implement basic database-functions like persisting a user or finding a user by his username.
Since I implemented some restraints, for example that it's not possible to delete a not existing user, i want to test my service.
My wish would be having a test that builds a temporary Neo4j graphdb like described in http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html.
But additionally I want to autowire my UserService into the test, do some operations on the temporary database and destroy the temporary database in the end again.
I'm expecting that I can solve this with TestConfigurations, but since I'm not really experienced with Spring or Neo4j, it's not that simple.

I have the following configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "de.myapp")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class UserTestConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration{

  @Bean
  public UserService userService() {
    return new UserBean();
  }

  @Bean
  public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    //This is probably wrong since i really want to connect to the impermanent db
    return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474");
  }

  @Bean
  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory("de.myapp");
  }
}
```

And the following test-class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TSUserTestConfiguration.class)
public class TSUserBeanTest {

  private GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

  @Autowired
  private TSUserService userService;

  @Before
  public void prepareTestDatabase() {
    graphDb = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
  }

  @After
  public void destroyTestDatabase() {
    graphDb.shutdown();
  }

  @Test
  public void createUserTest() {
    TSUser user = new TSUser("TestUser", "TestEmail");
    //This should create the user in the impermanent db
    userService.persistUser(user);
    //assert stuff here
  }
}
```

However, I get a NullPointer Exception for the graphDB in the destroy and I'm not even sure if I'm on the right way.
Does someone have an example for this scenario maybe?
Even a better way to integration-test my service on a temporary db is welcome.

Thanks and regards
Urr4

Comment: Please provide the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following Configuration for testing

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.services")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("my.repos")
public class MyTestingConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

  @Override
  @Bean
  public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    return new InProcessServer();
  }

  @Override
  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory("de.tsbros");
  }
}
```

And the following class for testing

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTestingConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class TSUserBeanTest {
  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  //testing here
}
```

using the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>${sdn.version}</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
  <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
  <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
  <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
  <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Everything like described [here](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/12/15/the-essence-of-spring-data-neo4j-4.html)
Works like a charm.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution can't help anymore.
"In SDN 4.1, the InProcessServer has been deprecated."
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#testing

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll keep in in mind for when i upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using SDN 4.x. - which version?

**SDN 4.0 RELEASE**

Instead of a `RemoteServer`, you will use an `InProcessServer` which internally starts a new instance of `CommunityNeoServer` on an available local port. It will manage shut down as well, so it's ideal and recommended for tests.
In your configuration, use this instead of the `RemoteServer`-

@Bean
  public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    return new InProcessServer();
  }

The dependencies required are documented in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_neo4jserver_bean).
Further reading, the test section in this [blog post](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/12/15/the-essence-of-spring-data-neo4j-4.html).

**SDN 4.1 M1**

The `InProcessServer` is no longer available, and instead you'll want to use the Embedded Driver which will set up for you the Impermanent graph database.
`ogm.properties` for the impermanent embedded store should contain-

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver
```

Dependencies required are documented in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.1.0.M1/reference/html/#_testing).
An example of upgrading your tests to use SDN 4.1 can be found [here](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/02/24/upgrading-spring-data-neo4j-4-1.html).

Comment: I'm going to try this later on, but on the first glance it looks really good, thank you!

Comment: Cool, if it works, please accept the answer. If not, we'll help :-)

Comment: I tried it and currently can't get it to work. I tried adding the dependencies as in the blog you posted, but it i build test with the PersistenceContext ContextConfguration, it always get the Failed to load ApplicationContext exception, telling me it "Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.PersistenceContext]: Specified class is an interface".

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? do i need to implement the Persistence context somehow? I use SDN 4.0 btw

Comment: Forget it, I'm an idiot :) I thought PersistenceContext was the neo4j testing configuration, that would somehow be autowired into the test.
I didn't even see, that the error says JAVAX.PERSISTENCE.PersistenceContext. I got the tests to run now, so thanks for your awesome answer :)

Comment: Just one tiny first-world-problem: When I use the InProcessServer, i get the warning "WARN 4j.ogm.authentication.CredentialsService:  XY - No credentials supplied". Is there a way to get my code warning-free? :)